# DBT problem with yml file: Profile my-bigquery-db in profiles.yml is empty

Tags: dbt

I am doing the DBT hello world tutorial [found here](https://dataschool.com/sql-optimization/start-modeling-data/), and I have created my first project on a windows machine.  My `profiles.yml` file looks like this:

```
    my-bigquery-db:
target: dev
outputs:
dev:
type: bigquery
method: service-account
project: abiding-operand-286102 
dataset: xxxDBTtestO1
threads: 1
keyfile: C:\Users\xxx\.dbt\abiding-operand-286102-ed9e3c9c13cd.json
timeout_seconds: 300
```

when I execute `dbt run` I get:

> > Running with dbt=0.17.2 Encountered an error while reading profiles:   ERROR Runtime Error
>
> dbt encountered an error while trying to read your profiles.yml
> file.
>
> Profile my-bigquery-db in profiles.yml is empty
>
> Defined profiles:
>
> - my-bigquery-db
> - target
> - outputs
> - dev
> - type
> - method
> - project
> - dataset
> - threads
> - keyfile
> - timeout_seconds

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance from both your code and the source walkthrough, this is just a `yml` config problem. YML is a markup language that is [white-space sensitive](https://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-05-15.html). And by just looking at the example that you may have pulled from - it doesn't look appropriately white spaced to me.

I'm not sure if you can simply copy from the below but it might be worth a shot.

```
my-bigquery-db:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: bigquery
      method: service-account
      project: abiding-operand-286102 
      dataset: xxxDBTtestO1
      threads: 1
      keyfile: C:\Users\xxx\.dbt\abiding-operand-286102-ed9e3c9c13cd.json
      timeout_seconds: 300
```

Basically - your `dbt` `profile.yml` needs to be setup with the sections at certain levels (not unlike python indentation or any other white spacing scheme).

[image]

Comment: wow! thanks. I had indented with tabs - but this didn't seem to work. when i indented with spaces, it worked.  Thank you.